# How to decrypt SSL traffic in android app with java?

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, vpn

I want to monitor all the traffic going through app or browser for that purpose i've used **ToyShark VPN**. It's working well for HTTP traffic but for HTTPS i can't get the complete URL as it is encrypted. So my question is how can i decrypt these URLs ?
I've tried installing **SSL Certificate** from [DigiCertificate](https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm) and used that key in my network_security_config.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <!-- Official Android N API -->
    <!--https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html-->
    <domain-config>
        <domain>baltimore-cybertrust-root.chain-demos.digicert.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
        <pin-set>
            <!-- Pin for: currency-converter-demo.pdm.approov.io -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">Fq9XqfZ2sKsSYJWqXrre8iqzERnWRKyVzUuT2/Pyaus=</pin>

            <!-- Backup Pin for: currency-converter-demo.pdm.approov.io -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=</pin>
        </pin-set>

        <!-- TrustKit Android API -->
        <!-- enforce pinning validation -->
        <trustkit-config enforcePinning="true" disableDefaultReportUri="true">
            <!-- Add a reporting URL for pin validation reports -->
            <report-uri>https://report.pdm.approov.io/pinning-violation/report</report-uri>
        </trustkit-config>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```

Now i need to make some code changes for decryption or what else is required? Apps like **WireShark** or **Fiddler** also decrypt what method or API do they use there must be some way to do the same in client side.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to run the HTTPS traffic through a TLS Inspection proxy (like Fiddler, mitmproxy, PolarProxy or SSLsplit), from which you will be able to get the decrypted traffic. To do this you'll need to configure the app/browser/phone to trust the root CA certificate of your TLS inspection proxy.